# The output of [lambda x:i*x for i in range(4)]

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I encountered such an interview question :

> Tell the output of the following snippet:

```
def num():
    return [lambda x:i*x for i in range(4)]
print([m(2)for m in num()])
```

I thought it simple and guessed `[0, 2, 4, 6]`

Unfortunately

```
In [1]: def num():
   ...:     return [lambda x:i*x for i in range(4)]

In [2]: print([m(2) for m in num()])
[6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Review its details

```
In [5]: for _ in num():
   ...:     print(_)
   ...: 
<function num.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7f042411dc80>
<function num.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7f0424182378>
<function num.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7f04240dfc80>
<function num.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7f042410ed08>
```

What's the name of such an obscure grammar to define a num,
How could it output such a rusult as `[6, 6, 6,6]`

I read the [python - Lambdas inside list comprehensions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070477/lambdas-inside-list-comprehensions)

```
>>> y = 3
>>> f = lambda: y
>>> f()
3
>>> y = 4
>>> f()
4
```

Put it in a standard way

```
In [15]: def foo(): return x

In [16]: x = 1; foo()
Out[16]: 1

In [17]: x = 4; foo()
Out[17]: 4
```

The explanation is not conceivable which does not illustrate closure.

the wikipedia's answer is better to take it as an obscure usage of closure to shadow vaiable

> This can also be achieved by variable shadowing (which reduces the scope of the non-local variable), though this is less common in practice, as it is less useful and shadowing is discouraged. In this example f can be seen to be a closure because x in the body of f is bound to the x in the global namespace, not the x local to g:

[Closure (computer programming) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))

```
x = 0

def f(y):
    return x + y

def g(z):
    x = 1  # local x shadows global x
    return f(z)

g(1)  # evaluates to 1, not 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambda` returns the value of `i` when called. The `lambda` is called after the loop has finished, so `i` is 3 by the time it's called.

Comment: it's because of [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). `i` is cached not at each moment in time but as a variable, whose final value is 3